# Why does Bitlocker not allow me to generate a pre-boot password? (only PIN)

Tags: windows, bitlocker

Currently I am using Bitlocker on two of my machines that all have TPM's, at first it would never ask me for a pre-boot authentication method because I forgot to edit a GPO that enabled this.

Now I did that and it allows me to choose one of three options:
-Enter a PIN
-Insert a USB flash drive
-Let Bitlocker automatically unlock my drive

I wasn't happy with the fact I couldn't only use numbers in the pin so I enabled the enhanced PIN in GPO allowing me to use special characters too, but really - I would like to use a much longer password than just 20 characters.

Is there any way to get the "Enter Password" option instead? My friend has it and we've not been able to figure out why it isn't here for me.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your friend has it due to the fact they are unlikely using a TPM

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. The menu you're seeing isn't for standalone protectors – it's actually the options that go together with a TPM-based protector. You get to choose from "TPM only", or "TPM + PIN", or "TPM + startup key". [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-countermeasures)

If you want to use a password, you will need to remove the TPM protector and use *only* a password, which might actually result in a weaker security level as the data is no longer hardware-bound. You should be able to use the `manage-bde -protectors` command to do this.

> but really - I would like to use a much longer password than just 20 characters.

20 should be fine. TPM+PIN is allowed to be shorter because it has hardware-limited attempts, much like an iPhone passcode.

Encryption passwords have to be long because once someone gets hold of your disk for only minutes, they can simply copy it and there's nothing that would stop them from trying massive numbers of passwords against the copy.

The PIN, meanwhile, is verified by the TPM itself – the hardware module doesn't simply give you a password hash; the only thing you can do with a PIN is submit it to the TPM for verification, and you'll get either a "yes" or "no" or "too many attempts, try again in 10 minutes".

For machines with a TPM 2.0, the standard rate limiting as configured by Windows [is documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/manage-tpm-lockout) to be:

> Windows 10 configures the maximum count to be 32 and the healing time to be 10 minutes. This means that every continuous ten minutes of powered on operation without an event which increases the counter will cause the counter to decrease by 1.

So after the initial free tries, an attacker will only get 144 attempts per day when guessing a TPM PIN – versus billions per day when cracking a password hash.

(As far as tamper resistance goes, a cheap TPM probably won't be entirely bullet-proof, but unless it's holding a few millions worth of bitcoins you're probably good. And at that point you might want to consider whether your password isn't going into a hardware keylogger...)